# IPv6 temporary address not renewed

Tags: networking, raspberrypi, ipv6

There something strange with my debian machine : IPv6 temporary addresses are not renewed at the end of their lifetime, they become deprecated and useless :

```
   tchupy@Raspihole:~ $ ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2a01:aaaa:bbb:cccc:xxxx:xxxx:53e1:eb8c/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 1763sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 2a01:aaaa:bbb:cccc:xxxx:xxxx:fe56:f540/64 scope global deprecated dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft 1763sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 2a01:aaaa:bbb:cccc::100/64 scope global noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:17d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft
```

If I shut/no shut the interface, it obtains a new temp IPv6 but it failed at the end..
I don't see what I miss
Here is an extract of sysctl variables

```
tchupy@Raspihole:~ $ sudo sysctl -a | grep net.ipv6.conf.eth0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_dad = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.max_addresses = 16
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.temp_prefered_lft = 3600
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.temp_valid_lft = 14800
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_oif_addrs_only = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr = 2
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

thx